# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: json, ajax, json.net

I am trying to send json through weservice but it gives an error in ajax call where i call this webservice.

My code to create  json is :

```
sb.Append('[');          
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["transferTo"].ToString())
            {
                case "Individual":
                    {                           
                        sb.Append("{pathImage:\"individual.png\",");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Stock":
                    {
                        sb.Append("{pathImage:\"stock.png\",");
                        break;
                    }

                case "Store":
                    {
                        sb.Append("{pathImage:\"store.png\",");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Inuse":
                    {
                        sb.Append("{pathImage:\"inuse.png\",");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Repair":
                    {
                        sb.Append("{pathImage:\"repair.png\",");
                        break;
                    }                                     
            }
           sb.Append("patharrow :\"arrow.png\"").Append("}");
           if (i != ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1) { sb.Append(','); }      
        }
        return sb.Append(']').ToString();
```

what is wrong with the code ?

The output is this :

```
{
    [
      {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "stock.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "store.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "repair.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "inuse.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, 
      {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }
    ]
}
```

what i have to do is in my ajax call which call the webservice code above :

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "assetHistory.aspx/getImagesPath",
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                //Check length of returned data, if it is less than 0 it means there is some status available
                if (data.d != "failure")
                {
                    json = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    var output = "<ul>";
                    alert("from json :" + json);
                    //wish to iterate here through each pathImage to store here
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Which language is this? This is not JavaScript.

Comment: "an error" — What error?

Comment: you open `{` in your for loop and you only close `}` one outside your loop... just close `}` in your loop or remove the openned `{` ;)

Comment: Don't build JSON as a string. Use a proper JSON library.

Comment: I wish to do something like this :{ [ { pathImage: "individual.png", patharrow: "arrow.png" }, { pathImage: "individual.png", patharrow: "arrow.png" }, { pathImage: "individual.png", patharrow: "arrow.png" }, { pathImage: "individual.png", patharrow: "arrow.png" }, { pathImage: "individual.png", patharrow: "arrow.png" }, { pathImage: "stock.png", patharrow: "arrow.png" } ] } –

Comment: @Quentin please see the edit of question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be appending `{` for each property

Replace

```
sb.Append("{pathImage:\"individual.png\",");
```

by

```
sb.Append("pathImage:\"individual.png\",");
```

**Edit**

As per the new info by OP, I think the key to the first property is missed

Since you have not shared the part of code which is generating first [ so I will explain to you why you are getting this error - Your JSON is missing the key before the first array value. That is {[]} is invalid. It should be {d:[]}.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data on doing this. what i want is a group of two which will have ''#" after each two so that i would  be able to split each with group of two in each row in my ajax call which is calling this webservice:

Comment: @testtest can you share final JSON output that you are getting?

Comment: i mean individual.png , arrow.png ,# ,stock.png, arrow.png,#, store.png,arrow.png ,#,.............. so on

Comment: is wish to do something like this :{
    [
      {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "stock.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }
    ]
}

Comment: @testtest you want this output, but what output do you get when you run your logic? Please add your current output and intended output in your question.

Comment: please see the edited question. It gives the error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: the output is this and still notworking : {
    "d": [{
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }, {
        pathImage: "individual.png",
        patharrow: "arrow.png"
    }]
}

Comment: and the error was : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

Comment: @testtest my bad, i think `[` in the beginning is for each image rather than group of images. Since you have not shared the part of code which is generating first `[` so I will explain to you why you are getting this error - Your JSON is missing the key before the first array value. That is `{[]}` is invalid. It should be `{d:[]}`

Comment: @testtest use jsonlint.com to validate your JSON and to find out common issues with it.